# Bea Weblogic 10.3.2 suddenly fails to restart with my Java Web app

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink, weblogic-10.x

Sorry for the general title here, but I am completely lost. I have an eclipse workspace, with a weblogic 10.3.2 server, with a java web app deployed to it. The war is under development, and I restart the server frequently, after updating parts of the code.

I recently changed a simple boolean parameter of a method call, and everything stopped working. It seems to not be related to my recent code change at all:

Full error message below, but first, here is the last "Caused by" line:

```
Caused by: com.bea.xml.XmlException: failed to load java type corresponding to 
           e=persistence@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
```

The web adress works, and I am online. Other searches for similar error messages implies that there are some mismatches in my JPA and/or Eclipselink versions. Also, there micht be problems with my persistence.xml, but that seems to be a consequence the "failed to load java type...".

My project is an old one, first derived from a maven archetype. I have been working on improvements and upgrades for this project for a long time, and just recently this error appeared. Other answers tells me to check my JPA and/or eclipselink jar versions. I've found my eclipselink reference (see picture), but this is an automatically imported library, which I haven't touched. I am afraid I might corrupt my project setup if I start to mess around with this on my own.

How can I proceed to figure out specifically what my problem is, and how I can fix it? The only thing I can think of, is that I have renamed my project, in the pom, war etc, and that there might be a mismatch between the old project name, and the new one. The thing is, I did this several weeks ago, and everything has worked fine after that.

setup:

[image]

Full error message:

```
<14-01-2016 13:35:53 CET> <Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160197> <Unable to load descriptor weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@17da690 finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@11803fb annotation: test-booking@/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/META-INF/persistence.xml of module test-booking.war. The error is weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: Unmarshaller failed
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:161)
    at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:323)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:788)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:411)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:759)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:768)
    at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptor(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:177)
    at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:101)
    at weblogic.deployment.ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.<init>(ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.setupPersistenceUnitRegistry(WebAppModule.java:1697)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.getWebClassLoader(WebAppModule.java:1489)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initClassLoader(WebAppServletContext.java:2890)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:420)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:466)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:414)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:924)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:391)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:1221)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:367)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:141)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:39)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:187)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:21)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:165)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:122)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:173)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:89)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: com.bea.xml.XmlException: failed to load java type corresponding to e=persistence@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.getPojoBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:371)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:326)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:336)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineRootType(UnmarshalResult.java:317)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshalResult.java:168)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:65)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:150)
    ... 40 more
.> 
<14-01-2016 13:35:53 CET> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application 'test-booking' due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'test-booking.war'.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'test-booking.war'
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:378)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:391)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: Error loading the persistence descriptor WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/META-INF/persistence.xml from the module test-booking.war.  See the following stack trace for nested errors: weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: Unmarshaller failed
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:161)
    at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:323)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:788)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:411)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:759)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:768)
    at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptor(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:177)
    at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:101)
    at weblogic.deployment.ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.<init>(ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.setupPersistenceUnitRegistry(WebAppModule.java:1697)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.getWebClassLoader(WebAppModule.java:1489)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initClassLoader(WebAppServletContext.java:2890)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:420)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:466)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:414)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:924)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:391)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:1221)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:367)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:141)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:39)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:187)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:21)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:165)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:122)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:173)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:89)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: com.bea.xml.XmlException: failed to load java type corresponding to e=persistence@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.getPojoBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:371)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:326)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:336)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineRootType(UnmarshalResult.java:317)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshalResult.java:168)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:65)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:150)
    ... 40 more

    at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptor(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:179)
    at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:101)
    at weblogic.deployment.ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.<init>(ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.setupPersistenceUnitRegistry(WebAppModule.java:1697)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.getWebClassLoader(WebAppModule.java:1489)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="test-booking">
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: You mention WLS 10.3.2 but are specifying persistence version 2.1 in your persistence.xml.  I don't think WLS 10 had JPA 2.1 support, which will prevent it from understanding and loading this file.

Comment: So strange.... It is working again, and the only thing I did, was switch the name of my eclipse project...